# Is there a way to set monthly deductions on a value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is for personal budget and savings within an excel sheet.

Say I have a loan of £1000, I will be paying £10 per month as of 7th December 2019 until the amount is paid off.

I would like to have a summary page on my sheet displaying the current outstanding debt. Currently I can only seem to work out how to deduct the £10 if date greater than/ equal to 7th. Which is not useful as each month after the 7th it'll display £990.

Comment: Has a set of 12 cells (one for each month) which evaluate to £10 if the date now() is after that month... then sum those values...

Answer (score 2):

What about `DATEDIF`:

```
=1000-((DATEDIF(43806,TODAY(),"M")+1)*10
```

Where:

- `1000` - Your starting loan
- `DATEFIF` - Function to calculate difference between two dates in months
- `43806` - 1st Parameter: Starting date > 7th December 2019
- `TODAY` - 2nd Paremter: Volatile function to feed the second parameter with current date
- `M` - 3rd Parameter: Calculate difference in whole **months**
- `+1` - Amount of months + 1 to account for all payments
- `*10` - Difference in months times 10 to deduct from starting loan

This would be volatile though, so use sparsely.

Comment: @kw19, if this has answered your question you should consider to mark it as answer. Please click the checkmark to the left.